# sum in python where list of list are in exponential

Tags: python, numpy, sum

I would like to write the following summation in python
[image]

The coefficients are given as the following list

```
cn=[1.2,0.4,0.6]
vn=[1e-6,5e-5,1e-6]
gn=[4.5e3,6.5e3,9e3]
t=np.linspace(0,10,100)
```

I tried the following

```
import numpy as np
cn=[1.2,0.4,0.6]
vn=[1e-6,5e-5,1e-6]
gn=[4.5e3,6.5e3,9e3]
t=np.linspace(0,10,100)
yt=np.sum(cn *np.exp(-vn*(t-gn)**2))
```

but am getting the error

```
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'list'
```

I would like to know where am getting it wrong or how to do this task

Comment: The error is because you are using lists instead of arrays. Try `vn=np.array([1e-6,5e-5,1e-6])` etc

Comment: Use numpy arrays instead of pure python lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a lazy way of fixing it:

```
 yt=np.sum(cn *np.exp(0-vn*(np.c_[t]-gn)**2), 1)
                      ^     ^------^        ^-^
```

I've highlighted the changes. The most important change is the `np.c_` which does two things:

1. It converts `t` to array
2. It makes `t` a column vector

1) serves as a "germ" for converting all the other lists to arrays via overloaded arithmetic operators.

Exception: the unary `-` in front of `vn` hits `vn` before it gets the chance to become an array. We put a zero in front the `-` to make it binary, thereby reducing it's precedence and closing the array coercion chain. This is not the most obvious fix but the one involving the least typing.

2) separates the time dimension from the summation dimension which is likely the correct interpretation. We have to add an eplicit `axis` argument to the sum which is the 1 we inserted at the very end of the expression.

Answer (score 3):

This run:

```
import numpy as np
cn=np.array([1.2,0.4,0.6])
vn=np.array([1e-6,5e-5,1e-6])
gn=np.array([4.5e3,6.5e3,9e3])
t=np.linspace(0,10,3)
yt=np.sum(cn * np.exp(-vn * (t - gn)**2))
```

1. Transform lists into numpy arrays
2. Make sure the matrix / array sizes are compatible, (ie. You can't add arrays of different lengths)

Example:
Add int to python list:

```
cn=[1.2,0.4,0.6]
cn+1
# output: TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

Add int to numpy array:

```
cn=np.array([1.2,0.4,0.6])
cn+1
# output: array([2.2, 1.4, 1.6])
```

Add numpy arrays with different dimensions:

```
cn = np.arange(1,3)
t = np.arange(1,100)
cn + t
# output: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (99,)
```

Add numpy arrays with the same dimensions:

```
cn = np.arange(1,3)
t = np.arange(3,5)
cn + t
# output: array([4, 6])
```

Comment: The answer should explain what you changed and why, not just show the code.

Answer (score 1):

If found two issues which I fixed but I am not sure is what you intended.

you don't need to convert the list to numpy array because you can perform arithmetic array between ndarray and list which will result ndarray.

Two error found are
1. shape of t was not matching with other arrays
2. you were trying to negate python list which doesn't support it

Also as you haven't put tn in your mathematical expression of summation above so I doubt it you want the length of t to be 3

```py
import numpy as np
cn=[1.2,0.4,0.6]
vn=[1e-6,5e-5,1e-6]
gn=[4.5e3,6.5e3,9e3]
t=np.linspace(0,10,3) # shape of t what 100 and not matching with other arrays
yt=np.sum(cn *np.exp(-(vn*(t-gn)**2))) # -(vn*(t-gn)**2)) wasn't wrapped in brackets
```

Comment: This still won't work. You can't multiply and subtract lists.

Comment: you actually can because t is ndarray, so t-gn will also be ndarray then vn*(t-gn) and so on, have you run the code? @Barmar

Comment: Good point. It happens to work in this case because `(-x)*y**2 == -(x*y**2)`.

Comment: It would be helpful to explain this detail in the answer, it's not obvious why it works.

Comment: This works but wanted t to have some big range not 3

Comment: Both cases need conversion from list to ndarray in this case it is done in numpy in other it is done in user code. So it shld work equally well